# Different google maps api key for each flavor build on Flutter iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

As i understand from [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) docs we need to declare google maps api key inside `AppDelegate.swift` like this:

```
GMSServices.provideAPIKey("YOUR KEY HERE")
```

is there a way to use different api key for each flavor build? like for example different api key for dev and production

Comment: Did you also do it on android or web?

Answer (score 7):

I used **Active Compilation Conditions** to solve this:

1. In Xcode, go to PROJECT -> Runner -> Build Settings and search for 'active compilation conditions'. Add a text value for each different flavor. [image: active compilation conditions]
2. in `AppDelegate.swift`, add preprocessor conditional statements to execute different code for different flavors, in our case providing a different API key:

   ```swift
   import UIKit
   import Flutter
   import GoogleMaps

   @UIApplicationMain
   @objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
     override func application(
       _ application: UIApplication,
       didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
     ) -> Bool {

       // Using active compilation conditions to provide the right API key for the right flavor.
       #if DEV
           GMSServices.provideAPIKey("<API key for DEV project>")
       #elseif QA
           GMSServices.provideAPIKey("<API key for QA project>")
       #elseif PROD
           GMSServices.provideAPIKey("<API key for PROD project>")
       #endif

       GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
       return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Please don't post code as images, use text and format as code blocks

Comment: Do you know what to do for Android?

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins with android you can specify a different key for each manifest of every flavor.