# flutter flavors for web in index.html and Android in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

I'm using [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) for two flavors (development, qa). I configured AppDelegate.swift for the two flavors [with this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66230981/3935156).

I now need to do those flavors on Android in android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest ...
  <application ...
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
               android:value="YOUR KEY HERE"/>
```

And in web index.html:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
```

How would I do both of those?

I do already have android/app/src/dev and android/app/src/qa folders because they have google-services.json flavor configuration files. So maybe another AndroidManifest.xml in those folders? Also would it contain everything that the main one has?

No idea how to do web.

Answer (score 0):

Android went from this in android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="MY_MAPS_API_KEY"/>
```

To:

android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="@string/google_maps_api_key"/>
```

android/app/build.gradle (:

```
flavorDimensions "default"
productFlavors {
    development {
        dimension "default"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Vepo Dev"
        resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "MY_DEV_MAPS_API_KEY"
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
    }
    qa {
        dimension "default"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Vepo Qa"
        resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "MY_QA_MAPS_API_KEY"
        applicationIdSuffix ".qa"
    }
}
```

For the web, I did this in main.dart / main_development.dart/ main_qa.dart:

```
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart'; // <----- Had to import this, it's not in the article

void createScriptElement() {
  /// Create a new JS element
  ScriptElement script = ScriptElement();

  /// On that script element, add the `src` and `id` properties
  script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${currentFlavor()}";
  script.id = "super-script";

  document.head.append(script);
}

void main() {

  if (kIsWeb) { // <------------- I had to add this, it's not in the article
    createScriptElement();
  }

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Taken from [here](https://gpalma.pt/blog/flutter-web-flavors/). Essentially it creates the HTML script tag from the dart, where you know the flavor, and inserts it into the HTML before the app runs.